# Value of property of an object is not replaced in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**app.js is:**

```
var app = angular.module('ControllerHierarchyAkaScopesWithinScopes',[]);

app.controller('ParentController',function($scope){ // this $scope is controller specific
    $scope.student = {name:"abc"};

});

app.controller('ChildController',function($scope){ // this $scope is controller specific
    $scope.setName = function(){
        $scope.student.name = "xyz";
    };
});
```

**And index.html is :**

```
<html ng-app="ControllerHierarchyAkaScopesWithinScopes">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="ControllerHierarchy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="ParentController">
            <div ng-contoller="ChildController">
                <a ng-click="setName()">click this to change value of $scope.student.name</a>
                {{setName()}}
                {{student}} 
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I visit `index.html` it shows `{"name":"abc"}` instead of {"name":"xyz"}. Why was value of `name` not replaced even though `setName()` has been called twice before `{{student}}` in `index.html`?

Comment: can you provide working plunkr? what angular version you use?

Comment: you have a typo here: `ng-contoller="ChildController"` should be _ng-cont**r**oller_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here: ng-contoller="ChildController" should be *ng-cont**r**oller*

if fix this - all work

```js
var app = angular.module('ControllerHierarchyAkaScopesWithinScopes',[]);

app.controller('ParentController',function($scope){ // this $scope is controller specific
    $scope.student = {name:"abc"};

});

app.controller('ChildController',function($scope){ // this $scope is controller specific
      $scope.setName = function(){
      console.log('setName', $scope);
        $scope.student.name = "xyz";
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="ControllerHierarchyAkaScopesWithinScopes">
        <div ng-controller="ParentController">
            <div ng-controller="ChildController">
                <a  ng-click="setName()">click this to change value of $scope.student.name</a>
                {{student}} 
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```